# python sqlite3 error in FreeBSD 9

Tags: python, freebsd, easy-install

Trying to install this ipython version. infact there's a django-starter project which uses buildout for his needs.. And that scripts tried to get ipython 0.11 with easy_install.I tried to grep everything out from this package but there's no ipython mentioned in any files at all. so I can't install newer version I need ipython0.11 to work. Please =)

```
    roman# easy_install "ipython==0.11" > errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 62, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 105, in run
  File "build/bdist.freebsd-9.0-RC1-amd64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-4FA3NZ/ipython-0.11/IPython/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-4FA3NZ/ipython-0.11/IPython/frontend/terminal/embed.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-4FA3NZ/ipython-0.11/IPython/frontend/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-4FA3NZ/ipython-0.11/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-4FA3NZ/ipython-0.11/IPython/core/history.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 85, in <module>
    register_adapters_and_converters()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 80, in register_adapters_and_converters
    register_adapter(datetime.date, adapt_date)
NameError: global name 'register_adapter' is not defined
```

**update:**

importing sqlite3 from python console gives this error:

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 85, in <module>
    register_adapters_and_converters()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 80, in register_adapters_and_converters
    register_adapter(datetime.date, adapt_date)
NameError: global name 'register_adapter' is not defined
```

Comment: Looks like a `sqlite3` thing. Can you run `python` and `import sqlite3` and try `sqlite3.register_adapter`? Or more basically, what happens if you do this from the command line? `python2.7 -c 'import sqlite3'`

Comment: ok birryree=) you've got it right, import sqlite3 doesn't work at all..

Comment: then you probably have to install the sqlite3 bindings - check my answer and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: checked your answer and this doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your error message and our exchange in the comments, I think the big problem is you might just be missing sqlite3 support for python.

From your error messages I take it you're running FreeBSD, so you should install the `databases/py-sqlite3` package from ports.

I don't know much about FreeBSD's ports system, but after you install the py-sqlite3 package, your problem should hopefully be cleared up.

I'm going to assume, from brief reading, you do something like this, assuming you have the ports tree on your system:

```
cd /usr/ports/databases/py-sqlite3
make && make install
```

Comment: it's already installed =) that's why I'm here in fact. this confuses me.. https://bitbucket.org/sirex/django-starter/src try to checkout this project , go to django-starter dir and type "make". if you, ofcourse not lazy to setup freebsd9 on your VM. on debian and osx it works.

Comment: @holms - how did you solve this problem?

Comment: with "port select" command because wrong python version was used